# Display 2 arrays in a table blade component

Tags: php, laravel, html-table, laravel-8

This code is working:

```
<table class="rounded-t-lg m-5 w-5/6 mx-auto bg-gray-200 text-gray-800">
<thead class="text-left border-b-2 border-gray-300">
<th class="px-4 py-3">#</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Tipo Doc.</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Documento</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Nombre</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Teléfono</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Correo</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Fecha</th>
<th class="px-4 py-3">Acciones</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
@if (count($pacientes)>0)
    @foreach($pacientes as $paciente)
        <tr class="bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200">
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->id}}</td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->tipoIdentificacion}}</td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->Identificacion}}</td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->NombreCompleto}}</td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->Telefono}}</td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->Correo}}</td>
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$paciente->created_at}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ url('/pacientes/' . $paciente->id . '/edit') }}">
                    Editar
                </a>
                <form action="{{ url('/pacientes/' . $paciente->id) }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Borrar">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
</tbody>
```

but this table is not ***reusable***. In order for it work as a component, it has to work with any numbers of title and data, at the end of each row there is an action buttons(edit or delete). I've save the titles(th) in an array and they are displaying correctly with a `foreach`, but i cant fill the table with the other data in its order. can you please help me?

Comment: Not clear what you're talking about. What do you consider titles, and what do you consider values? Can you give an example of the inputs? Side note: you don't need `@if (count($pacientes)>0)`, you can go straight to the `foreach`. It simply won't run if there are no elements in the array.

Comment: The titles are: name, id, phone. And the values are: jhon, 8388, 900339393

Comment: Yes, those are values, but which variables are considered titles and which values? Or do you have an associative array?

Comment: they are not associative, they are 2 independent arrays, one with column names and other with the data

Comment: Use the key in `foreach`, like `foreach $data as $key => $value` and then access the same key in the other array `$otherArray[$key]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Laravel's [Components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components).

> Components and slots provide similar benefits to sections, layouts,
> and includes; however, some may find the mental model of components
> and slots easier to understand. There are two approaches to writing
> components: class based components and anonymous components.

I will use *class based components* here.

**STEP 1**

Create a class based component with the `make:component` Artisan command. below:

```
php artisan make:component TableLayout
```

This command will create two files along with its associated scaffolding directories. `App\View\Components\TableLayout.php` and `resources\views\components\table-layout.blade.php` which is the view partial.

Below is the `TableLayout` component.

> You should define the component's required data in its class constructor.
> All public properties on a component will automatically be made available
> to the component's view.
> It is not necessary to pass the data to the view from the
> component's `render` method:

```php
<?php
// App\View\Components\TableLayout.php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class TableLayout extends Component
{
    public $dataObject;
    public $dataObjectIdLabel;
    public $routeUrl;
    public $thsTds;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dataObject, $dataObjectIdLabel, $routeUrl, $thsTds )
    {
        $this->dataObject = $dataObject;
        $this->dataObjectIdLabel = $dataObjectIdLabel;
        $this->routeUrl = $routeUrl;
        $this->thsTds = $thsTds;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.table-layout');
    }
}
```

Below is the corresponding `table-layout` view.

> When your component is rendered, you may display the
> contents of your component's public variables by echoing the variables by name:

```html
 <!-- resources\views\components\table-layout.blade.php -->

<table class="rounded-t-lg m-5 w-5/6 mx-auto bg-gray-200 text-gray-800">

    <thead class="text-left border-b-2 border-gray-300">
    @foreach(array_keys($thsTds) as $th)
    <th class="px-4 py-3">{{$th}}</th>
    @endforeach
    <th class="px-4 py-3">Acciones</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @if (count($dataObject)>0)
    @foreach($dataObject as $data)
        <tr class="bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200">
        @foreach(array_values($thsTds) as $td)
            <td class="px-4 py-3">{{$data->$td}}</td>
        @endforeach
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url($routeUrl . $data->$dataObjectIdLabel . '/edit') }}">
            Editar
            </a>
            <form action="{{ url($routeUrl . $data->$dataObjectIdLabel) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <input type="submit" value="Borrar">
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endif
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**STEP 2**

Then in any other *'blade view'* file/template i.e `resources\views\example.blade.php`, make use of the newly created reusable component.

[Rendering Components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-components)

> To display a component, you may use a Blade component tag within one of your Blade
> templates. Blade component tags start with the string `x-` followed by the
> kebab case name of the component class:

```html
<!-- resources\views\example.blade.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    @php ($thsTds = [
    "#"=> "id",
    "Tipo Doc."=>"tipoIdentificacion",
    "Documento"=>"Identificacion",
    "Nombre"=>"NombreCompleto",
    "Teléfono"=>"Telefono",
    "Correo"=>"Correo",
    "Fecha"=>"created_at"
    ])
    
    <x-table-layout :data-object="$paciente" data-object-id-label="id" route-url="/pacientes/" :ths-tds="$thsTds" />

    </body>
</html>
```

## Notes

[Passing Data To Components](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components)

> You may pass data to Blade components using HTML attributes.
> Hard-coded, primitive values may be passed to the component using simple
> HTML attribute strings. PHP expressions and variables should be passed
> to the component via attributes that use the `:` character as a **prefix**:

[Casing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#casing)

> Component constructor arguments should be specified using `camelCase`,
> while `kebab-case` should be used when referencing the
> argument names in your HTML attributes.